# Timer/Refresh functionality for text box

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading, timer, refresh

In my application, I have two text boxes accompanied with two labels: "Connected" and "Not Connected". As seen in my code, if a connection is established, the "Connected" text box will fill with Green, indicating a network connection. It will be red if not.

The functionality of connection detection is working just fine, however, I have to re-open the application for it to detect the change. I am looking for a way to refresh the application every 5-10 seconds or so automatically to detect any change in connectivity. I don't want to flush out the contents of any other field or box, just the color text boxes. A soft polling loop so to speak. How would I go about doing this using the Timer method. Should I create a new thread in which to run the timer and refresh the box?

Thanks.

```
  if (System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable() == false)
        {
            noConnect.Select();  //if not connected, turn box red
            noConnect.BackColor = Color.Red;

        }

        else
        {
            netConnect.Select();  // if connected, turn box green
            netConnect.BackColor = Color.Lime;

        }

        //need to refresh box/application without losing other box/field contents 
        //in order to constantly check connectivity around 5-10 seconds or so
        //constantly check connectivity
```

Comment: @HenkHolterman `BackColor` is winform and not WPF :)

Comment: Why poll?  Does the network  not provide 'OnConnect', 'OnDisconnect' events or overridable functions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this would work

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        var timer = new Timer();
        timer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_Tick);
        timer.Interval = 10000; //10 seconds
        timer.Start();
    }

    void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (your_function_call())
        {
            netConnect.BackColor = Color.Green;
        }
        else
            netConnect.BackColor = Color.Red;
    }
```

The timer_Tick would be repeatedly called every interval and you can poll your status and update controls. Because the timer call back is called in the UI-thread you can update any UI elements.

From [Timer Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28SYSTEM.WINDOWS.FORMS.TIMER%29;k%28TIMER%29;k%28DevLang-CSHARP%29&rd=true)

> A Timer is used to raise an event at user-defined intervals. This
>   Windows timer is designed for a single-threaded environment where UI
>   threads are used to perform processing. It requires that the user code
>   have a UI message pump available and always operate from the same
>   thread, or marshal the call onto another thread.   When you use this
>   timer, use the Tick event to perform a polling operation or to display
>   a splash screen for a specified period of time. Whenever the Enabled
>   property is set to true and the Interval property is greater than
>   zero, the Tick event is raised at intervals based on the Interval
>   property setting.

This solution uses `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` that calls the tick on UI-thread. If you use `System.Timers.Timer` the callback won't be on UI-thread.

Comment: Thank you very much. The connection detection is working just fine now!

Comment: Was looking for an easy method to update a `textbox` with elapsed time and this was the most simplistic approach +1

Answer (score 1):

just create the [timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.aspx). it well run on his own thread without you doing any thing else.

Comment: the event raised well be in the main, the time checking in a separate thread.

Comment: No, the 'time checking' is done as part of the MessagePump. When it stalls so does your timer.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a timer somewhere in your application

```
var timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
timer.Interval = 5000; // every 5 seconds
timer.Elapsed = (s, e) => {
    // Your code
};
timer.Start();
```

Note: please be aware that your code in the Elapsed event handler can/will run on another thread!

Comment: Just use a `Windows.Forms.Timer` to avoid all threading issues.